# scoped_ptr ownership

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

I was reading [an article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8394/Smart-Pointers-to-boost-your-code) and I found a small example to demonstrate the use of `boost::scoped_ptr<T>`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_array.hpp>

static int count = 0;

class printer
{
    int m_id;

public:
    printer(void) :
        m_id(count++)
    {
    }

    ~printer(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Printer " << m_id
                  << " destroyed" << std::endl;
    }
};

int
main(void)
{
    boost::scoped_ptr<printer> p1(new printer);
    boost::scoped_ptr<printer> p2(new printer);
    std::cout << "Exiting test program" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The only thing I didnt understand in the article was this statement:

> using `scoped_ptr`, you indicate that ownership transfer is not intended or allowed.

Maybe it was the wrong article to begin with as a beginner on this topic, but what exactly the above line means?

Comment: Yeah, it was the wrong article. The answer to this question is an entire C++ book, but SO won't let me post an answer that long.

Comment: entire C++ book? Okay! Although, I sincerely doubt that.. Can you make a small attempt to give a small overview. I will try my best to understand

Comment: Did you try posting 2 answers each half as long?

Comment: @thang: Yeah :( I got as far as 1/16th-sized posts but then gave up.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So in theory, you can do 16 posts each 1/16th as long.

Comment: I want to mark as dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one, but the system has been broken by a premature feature roll-out.

Comment: I'm assuming this is simply that the declaring scope of the smart pointer cannot be changed, since scoped_ptr is a stack class. Passing this into another scope would cause two identical pointers to the same region of memory (due to the copy constructor that would have to be present to support this) and thus, one scope exiting would cause the destruction of the object and cause the other pointer to become invalid. Of course, this is a rambling guess, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most smart pointers have ownership of the object they are pointing to - they are in charge of destroying that object when the time comes. However, different smart pointers have different *ownership semantics*. That is, they tell the user of that smart pointer how the ownership may or may not be transferred, how it is shared amongst objects, when the object should be deleted, and so on. Using a certain smart pointer describes your *intent* with regards to the ownership of that object. Ownership can be transferred to other functions or objects.

`boost::scoped_ptr` has very strict ownership semantics. It doesn't allow any transfer of ownership at all. It achieves this by being non-copyable (so you can't pass it to another function by value).

As another example, a `std::unique_ptr` is also fairly strict. Its special ability is that it can be moved from. Passing an `std::unique_ptr` to a function as an rvalue will let that function steal ownership of the object. The original `std::unique_ptr` loses that ownership immediately. This ensures that ownership is only ever held by one `std::unique_ptr`.

The equivalent to `boost::scoped_ptr` in C++11 is a `const std::unique_ptr`. This is because making it `const` prevents any moving and thus ownership can not be transferred.

An easy way to see how important ownership semantics are is with an example. Let's say you're using an evil developer's library and it has a function that you don't know the implementation of, such as:

```
cat* foo();
```

You know this function returns a pointer to a `cat`. However, it's a raw pointer. You have no idea whether you should be destroying the cat (with `delete`) at some point or if the library will do it for you. You don't even know if the object was actually dynamically allocated. You have no idea if the library still keeps hold of the `cat`. In the past, if you had a function like this, you would need to look up the documentation to find out what to do. However, now that we have smart pointers in addition to raw pointers, raw pointers have their own ownership semantics - the most relaxed of them all. It says "You better trust me that I keep this `cat` valid for as long as you pass it around but I'll be the one managing it. Don't keep it for too long."

However, a wise and kind library developer would now write this function like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<cat> foo();
```

So how does this help? Well, the `std::unique_ptr` tells you a lot. It tells you that the function is giving up ownership of the `cat` object to you. The `cat` is now your sole responsibility. It's also very helpful in giving you a smart pointer because you don't need to think about `delete`ing it. You can just use the pointer and when it goes out of scope, the object will be destroyed. Or, if you want to, you can transfer ownership to *another* function.

This doesn't mean that only one pointer will ever have ownership of the `cat` though. As the proud new owner, it's up to you to decide what happens next. It's perfectly reasonable for you to decide that you want to start sharing ownership of your `cat`:

```
std::unique_ptr<cat> up = foo();
std::shared_ptr<cat> sp(up.release());
```

The wise and kind `foo` library developer only told you what *her* intentions were. She gave you the `cat` and now you're the owner. Now you can provide your own ownership semantics.

In this way, a `boost::scoped_ptr` is a bit like a greedy `cat` hoarder who will never share the `cat` with anybody, never give the cat to anybody, and will keep it until the day they die.

Comment: That clears a lot of things :) thanks a ton!